# Where to find my private key on monero gui?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I'm new to this so I was wondering where to find my private (view)key in the Monero gui win x64. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under **Settings** tab, click on the **Show seed & keys** button at the top. And watch your back - as it will show the seed and all the keys, you don't want someone seeing / recording this from behind your back.